# Extract the different recored in two table

Tags: sql, oracle, set-operations

I have two tables - `table1` and `table2`.
Both tables have the same columns.

I want to extract the record differences - meaning extract records in `table1` not in `table2`, and extract records in `table2` not in `table1`.

How I can do that by using SQL in Oracle Sys?

Answer (score 3):

to get all differences in **both** tables in **one** result set you can use

```
select columnlist
from tableA
minus
select columnlist
from tableB
union all
select columnlist
from tableB
minus
select columnlist
from tableA
```

Comment: It's `minus` in Oracle instead of `except`

Answer (score 0):

> [MINUS](http://oreilly.com/catalog/mastorasql/chapter/ch07.html)   Takes the result set of one SELECT statement, and removes
>   those rows that are also returned by a second SELECT statement.

This query will return all rows that are in table1, but not in table2:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 where pk_col not in(select pk_col from table2)

select * from table2 where pk_col not in(select pk_col from table1)
```

Comment: This is an English-only site; please write in English.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.column1,t1.column2 from table1 t1 except select t2.column1,t2.column2 from table 2 t2 UNION all select t2.column1,t2.column2 from table 2 t2 except select t1.column1,t1.column2 from table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.Id,t1.name,t2.Id,t2.name from table1 t1 ,table2 t2 where t1.Id and t1.Name not in(select * from  table2) and t2.Id,t2.name not in (select * from table 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

RomanKonz's solution, with additional information which table actually contains the rows (I usually use WITH to simplify the actual UNION ALL / MINUS part):

```
with 
  v_a as (
    select *
    from tableA), 
  v_b as (
    select *
    from tableB)
select * from 
(
 (select 'A only' src, v.* from v_a v
  minus 
  select 'A only' src, v.* from v_b v
 ) 
 union all
 (select 'B only' src, v.* from v_b v
  minus
  select 'B only' src, v.* from v_b v
 )
) order by primarykeycolumn, src
```